# Code::Blocks debugger shows some other path which isn't included in the project

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I'm trying to use code::blocks debugger. I followed [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks) basic tutorial on how to do it. I also watched two videos on you tube. I was actually trying it on a bigger file which had its declaration & implementation in separate files (one was header file tree.h, one had its implementation tree.cpp & the last one had implementation_tree.cpp main function to check the header file) but it didn't work so I tried it on a very simple program. But now debugger shows this error

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: F:\Coding\test\test\
Adding source dir: F:\Coding\test\test\
Adding file: F:\Coding\test\test\bin\Debug\test.exe
Changing directory to: F:/Coding/test/test/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

[debug]Command-line: F:\Coding\Data Structures\tree.h -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args F:/Coding/test/test/bin/Debug/test.exe
[debug]Working dir : F:\Coding\test\test

Starting debugger: F:\Coding\Data Structures\tree.h -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args F:/Coding/test/test/bin/Debug/test.exe
failed
```

Whatever is in this line **[debug]Command-line:** is the address of my tree.h file which I was trying to debug earlier. But now I've removed all the breakpoints & everything related to that file from Code::Blocks & even changed that file's location but it still shows that same address in **Starting debugger:**. I've also rebuilt my test program after deleting everything related to it several times but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using GDB.

I'm so sorry if this question sounds very silly as I'm trying this for the first time & not being able to proceed through any tutorials or any other forum or anything else. I've also seen other related questions on stackoverflow but none of them works for me. So, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Compiler -> Search Directories.. Delete all paths from there.